# On Shabbos or Yom Tov can one wait for the chazzan and join him to say שוכן עד?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tzibur-community, shacharis-morning-prayer, hefsek-interruption

[O Ch 53 (3) MB [9]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=160&hilite=) says that after an individual finishes the פסוקי דזמרה   he should go straight on and say ישתבח and not wait for the chazzan.

On Shabbos or Yom Tov, is it permitted to stop and wait just before  שוכן עד (or at any other point before ישתבח)     and resume with the chazzan or is one obliged to go straight on and say ישתבח?

Comment: What do you suspect is unique about Shochen Ad?

Comment: @DoubleAA Nothing special - but sometimes a more tuneful chazzan takes over there. I amended the question.

Comment: What's the difference between Shabbos and weekday?

Comment: Note that the original minhag was to say shokhen ad after yishtabah.

Answer (score 1):

Ma'aseh Rav # 126 indicates that that is what the [Gra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) did.

> בשחרית מתפללין בפירוד עד שוכן עד ומשם ואילך מתחיל הש"ץ והוא בעצמו
>   התחיל ב"ש ואמר פסד"ז בקול רם עד שוכן עד וכן ביום טוב
>
> By Shacharis they would pray separately until "Shochen Ad" and from
>   that point on the chazzan would begin, and he himself would begin with
>   "Baruch She'amar" and he would say Pesukei D'zimra in a raised voice
>   until "Shochen Ad", and the same on Yom Tov.